# AngularJS Routing not doing anything not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have following PhoneCat tutorial combined with an angular seed project. Now i come into the problem, i can't get routing to work / load, no errors occur and everything seems fine. Can't even seem to get, the basic redirect to work. I'm lost what to do.

Here is my app.js where i think the error is

```
'use strict';

var elgrossisten = angular.module('elgrossisten', [
  'ngRoute',
  'elgrossistenControllers'
]);

elgrossisten.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/elnrlist.html',
        controller: 'SearchElNrCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/search'
      });
  }]);
```

controller

var elgrossistenControllers = angular.module('elgrossisten', []);

```
elgrossistenControllers.controller('SearchElNrCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.elnrs = [
    {'elnr': '10150135',
     'avgprice': '18.75',
     'lastupdated': '01-01-2014'},
    {'elnr': '10170135',
     'avgprice': '18.75',
     'lastupdated': '01-01-2014'},
    {'elnr': '10110135',
     'avgprice': '18.75',
     'lastupdated': '01-01-2014'}
  ];
});
```

And how i load my scripts.

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give an example of what url you are going to, what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Comment: elgrossisten/app/#/search/ should hopefully redirect to my controller and view

while 

elgrossisten/app/ should redirect me to #/search

Comment: sloppy naming was the reason

angular.module('elgrossisten', [
  'ngRoute',
  'elgrossistenControllers'
]);

should have been

angular.module('elgrossistenControllers', [
  'ngRoute',
  'elgrossistenControllers'
]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elgrossisten` module depends on two others:

```
angular.module('elgrossisten', [
   'ngRoute',
   'elgrossistenControllers'
]);
```

Those two modules need to be defined before you instantiate your `elgrossisten` module.
Maybe try loading your scripts this way?

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

You need to include your dependant modules before you load your app js (as this one depends on others). Although I don't really understand why no error is showing for you. If you provide some more information, or a plnkr, I could help you out a bit more.